# Creating a property from a CGFloat array - iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, properties, cgfloat

Trying to create a property, so I can set CGfloat array values on an instance of a class. Having a hard time figuring out how to do it. The CGFloat needs to have "size" [2] variable and numeric components like below:

```
CGFloat locations[2] = {1.0, 0.0};
```

Here is how it looks in the class itself (this works), before I created the property  in an attempt to set these values from an instance (this creates a gradient BTW via drawRect in a UIView sunclass):

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGColorSpaceRef myColorspace=CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGFloat locations[2] = {1.0, 0.0};
CGFloat components[8] = { 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,  0.5, 0.25, 1.0, 1.0 };
CGGradientRef myGradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(myColorspace, components,locations, num_locations);
CGContextDrawLinearGradient (context, myGradient, myStartPoint, myEndPoint, 0);
```

I tried creating a property like below in the .h

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat locations;
```

and in the .m

```
@synthesize locations;
```

But I cant figure out how to properly set the values for the [size] and the components from the instance. Also I get errors when I set up the property: ERROR: "Passing 'CGFloat' (aka 'float') to parameter of incompatible type 'const CGFloat *' (aka 'const float *'); take the address with &"

you can get the project here is you feel like taking a look [tinyurl.com/cmgy482](http://tinyurl.com/cmgy482) Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476843/create-an-array-of-integers-property-in-objective-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From another answer found here: ["C arrays are not one of the supported data types for properties".](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1983022/1408546) I think that was my issue. The solution I used, is to make the property an NSMutableArray and to convert the values to a CGFloat.

.h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *locations;
```

.m

```
CGFloat locationsFloat[[locations count]];

    for (int i = 0; i < [locations count]; i++) {
        NSNumber *number = [locations objectAtIndex:i];
        locationsFloat[i] = [number floatValue];        
    }
```

viewController

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSMutableArray *arrayPoints = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];    
    [arrayPoints addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0]];
    [arrayPoints addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0]];

    [myInstance setLocations:arrayPoints];

...
```

Answer (score 3):

Ideally you would be able to just declare your property like this:

```
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat locations[2];
```

Alas, clang does not allow you to create a property with an array type.

One alternative is to use a pointer type instead.  You probably want to write a comment to explain how many elements it points to:

```
#define kMyClassLocationCount 2

// This is an array of kMyClassLocationCount elements.  The setter copies
// the new elements into existing storage.
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat *locations;
```

To implement it, you need to create the instance variable and define the getter and setter:

```
@implementation MyClass {
    CGFloat _locations[kMyClassLocationCount];
}

- (CGFloat *)locations {
    return _locations;
}

- (void)setLocations:(CGFloat *)locations {
    memcpy(_locations, locations, kMyClassLocationCount * sizeof *_locations);
}
```

Note that you don't need `@synthesize`, because you have explicitly defined everything that `@synthesize` might generate.

When you use an instance of the class, you can read an individual location like this:

```
CGFloat location1 = myInstance.locations[1];
```

and you can set an individual location like this:

```
myInstance.locations[0] = 0.5;
```

and you can set all of the locations at once like this:

```
CGFloat newLocations[2] = { 7, 11 };
myInstance.locations = newLocations;
```

Answer (score 2):

i think you had better code like this:

```
NSArray * locations = [[NSArray alloc ] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f],[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f],nil];
```