# Objective-C. Property for C array

Tags: objective-c, arrays, properties, instance-variables

I need something like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) int field[10][10];
```

but this code doesn't work. How to replace it? I need both setter and getter methods

Comment: Refer this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476843/create-an-array-of-integers-property-in-objective-c

Comment: Also, why can't you simply use an NSArray?

Comment: 1)You advice convert to NSArray and convert from. You also need to convert simple variables of int type to something like NSValue objects. Or I need to rewrite all the previous code to use an NSArray instead of c arrays. 2)I use a multiple c arrays of int instead of one NSArray of objects with parameters because the variables are enough simple and these arrays represent something like logic layers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it if you wrap the array in a struct. Structs are supported in @property notation (see CGRect bounds on CALayer, for example).

First define your struct:

```
typedef struct {
    int contents[10][10];
} TenByTenMatrix;
```

Then, in your class interface, you can do:

```
@property (assign) TenByTenMatrix field;
```

Note that in this case, you can only get or set the whole array using the property. So you can't do

```
self.field.contents[0][0] = 1;
```

You'd have to do

```
TenByTenMatrix temp = self.field;
temp.contents[0][0] = 1;
self.field = temp;
```

Answer (score 4):

If I understood you correctly, you need something like this:

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) int** field;
```

Note that you can't use `retain` here because it is only available for objects (and `int` is a primitive type).

Then you can use this in a following way:

```
    //some initialization - just an example, can be done in other way
self.field = malloc(10 *  sizeof(int));

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    self.field[i] = malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
}

//actual usage
self.field[2][7] = 42;
int someNumber = self.field[2][7];
```

Because property's type is `assign`, you have to take care of memory management. You can create custom setter for `field` property and call `free()` in it.

Answer (score 0):

Write setter and getter

```
- (int) field:(int)i j:(int)j {
    return field[i][j];
}

- (void)setField:(int)i j:(int)j toValue:(int)value {
    field[i][j] = value;
}
```

Comment: I meaned to store the whole array, not separate values

Comment: This won't work. Setters for Objective-C properties take exactly one parameter, and getters don't take any.

Comment: I meaned a 2 methods to set and to get a whole array as it could be with using of @property. So this answer look likes as 30-50% of the correct answer.

Comment: @MichałCiuba if you want only array you can use -(int **)getField
{
 return field;
}

Answer (score 0):

It s pretty simple.

```
    @interface MyClass
    {
        int _fields[10][10]; 
    }

    @property(readonly,nonatomic) int **fields;

    @end

    @implementation MyClass

    - (int *)fields
    {
        return _fields;
    }

    @end
```

Use readonly in property as it is a fixed pointer, which you wont be changing, which doesn't mean that you can't modify the values in the array.