# Is it a bad practice to use C array inside Objective C class?

Tags: objective-c

I wonder is there any drawbacks when use alloc/free with pure C array inside Objective-C class?
For example:

```
#import "CVPatternGrid.h"

@implementation CVPatternGrid

@synthesize row = _row;
@synthesize column = _column;
@synthesize count = _count;
@synthesize score = _score;

- (id)initWithRow:(NSInteger)row column:(NSInteger)column {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _grid = [self allocateNewGrid:row column:column];
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSInteger)moveCount {
    return _count;
}

- (bool**)allocateNewGrid:(NSInteger)row column:(NSInteger)column {
    bool **p = malloc(row * sizeof(bool*));
    for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i) {
         p[i] = malloc(column * sizeof(bool));
    }
    return p;
}

- (void)generateNewGrid:(NSInteger)row column:(NSInteger)column {
    [self freeGrid];
    _grid = [self allocateNewGrid:row column:column];
    _count = [self.algorithmDelegate generateGrid:_grid];
    _score = _count * 100;
}

- (BOOL)isMarkedAtRow:(NSInteger)row column:(NSInteger)column {
    return YES;
}

- (void)freeGrid {
    for (int i = 0; i < _row; ++i) {
        free(_grid[i]);
    }
    free(_grid);
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [self freeGrid];
}

@end
```

Comment: It's not done very often, but there are cases where it's appropriate.  Be aware that C arrays and properties don't work and play well together -- it can be done but requires a minor tap dance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's perfectly normal to use a C array in an Obj-C class. There are no low level data types in Obj-C — every class, including NSArray, NSString, etc, is using primitive C types internally.

However you are doing a few things wrong:

Do not use `@synthesize` unless you need to. In this case you don't need it, so delete those lines of code.

Do not use `_foo` to access variables unless you need it, again in this case you don't need it in any of your use cases (except, arguably, in your init and dealloc methods. But I would argue it should not even be used there. Other people disagree with me). My rule is to only use `_foo` when I run into performance issues when using `self.foo` syntax. There are also edge case issues such as KVO where you might run into problems when using an accessor inside init/dealloc. In the real world I have never run into any of those edge cases in more than 10 years of writing Obj-C — I always use accessors, unless they're too slow.

Some implementation details about how to declare an `@property` of a C array: [Objective-C. Property for C array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17548425/objective-c-property-for-c-array)