# pass int array between view controllers

Tags: objective-c, arrays, int, viewcontroller

I have an in integer array that I'd like to pass from one view controller to another.

I can pass strings from one view to a label in another however I'm not able to do that with an int array.

Basically I have declared the following in viewController_A: -

int totalArray[30];

and I want to pass it to viewController_B

Comment: show the code where you are trying to pass the array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There shouldn't be any difference between passing an integer array and a string from one ViewController to another.

Sending data between ViewControllers is relatively simple, Here's a link to something I found useful when I first sent data between ViewControllers.
[Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Make sure your array declaration is strong:

`@property (nonatomic, strong)NSMutableArray *exampleArray;`

Edit: Trying to pass an integer array would be a lot more work than holding your values inside an NSMutableArray or NSArray since you cannot declare a c-style array as a property without a work-around as can seen in this post [Create an array of integers property in Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476843/create-an-array-of-integers-property-in-objective-c)

If you look at robottobor's answer on that link you will see how you can implement the array as a property, but again I strongly suggest you use an NSMutableArray or NSArray.

Comment: I wrote the following but it doesn't work. Do I have to use a NSMutableArray... I just want to pass an integer array. @property (strong, nonatomic)int *testArray[30];

Comment: Note that the OP isn't passing an NSArray.  An `int[]` isn't an object, so standard property attributes do not apply.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a property in the receiving view controller:
  @property(nonatomic, strong) NSArray *array

Then in prepareForSegue just access that property 
  destViewController.array = intArray

Comment: Note that the OP isn't passing an NSArray.

Answer (score 0):

Here, I describe easy way to pass array between two controller.

Suppose you want two pass array from controller1 to controller2.

> 1. create array in controller2.
> 2. import controller2 file in controller1.
> 3. create object of controller2 file.

Code:

```
controller2 *cn2 = (controller2 *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"storyboard_identifier"]; // create object of second controller

    cn2.array_name = array_name; //pass first controller array to second controller

[self.navigationController pushViewController:cn2 animated:YES]; // redirect to second controller
```

Thank You.