# Standard C Arrays in Singletons

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, singleton

I'm trying to incorporate a standard C-array of floats into a singleton so that it can be accessed globally. Is this even possible? I feel the problem lies with the creation of the array; because It will not let me simply produce an array in the same way as I would in a header file.

For example:

```
@interface globalVariables : NSObject{

    float hzArray[4]; //arrays of floating point variables.

}

@property(nonatomic) float hzArray[4]; //ERROR RETURNED HERE

+(globalVariables *) getVariable;

@end
```

returns the error:

`Property cannot have array or function type 'float[4]'`

I realise this is probably a very rudimentary question, but I appreciate any advice you can give me.

Thanks,
Tom.

Comment: Why not use an NSArray and box the floats into NSNumbers?

Comment: It seems the issue comes from the use of your property. I am not fully sure, but I don't think you can mix c and objc properties/variables. Try making the float array a const float hzArray[4]; and see if that works.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476843/create-an-array-of-integers-property-in-objective-c

Comment: A "singleton" is simply an API that returns the pointer to something.  The "something" can be anything you want.

Comment: @property(nonatomic) float *hzArray; will work, but you'll need to make the malloc and free calls yourself

Comment: Larme, thanks for the link, it appears C Arrays are not supported data types for properties. I'll work on adjusting my program to work with NSArray. Thanks, Tom.

Comment: You don't need to have a property to have a singleton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you read on, [check out the question that Larme linked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/476843/1292061).

Done? Ok. The short answer here is that you can't easily have arrays as properties in Objective-C, and you probably don't want to anyways. To do what you seem to want, I strongly recommend you use an `NSArray`, as some of the other commenters have mentioned, and store your `float` values in it, wrapped in `NSNumber` objects. Something like:

```
@interface GlobalVariables : NSObject
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *hzArray;
+ (GlobalVariables *)getVariable;
@end

@implementation GlobalVariables
+ (GlobalVariables *)getVariable {
    GlobalVariables *gv = [[self alloc] init];
    // init the array in some meaningful way
    gv.hzArray = @[@(1), @(2), @(3)];
    return gv;
}
@end
```

<sup>Note that I've renamed the class to `GlobalVariables`, with a capitalized first letter, because that's the convention for class names in Objective-C.</sup>

Comment: In theory one could use an NSValue property containing an array pointer.  Of course, there is no need to use properties to implement a singleton anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advise, i've managed to get this integrated into my program.